# Cannot inject bean of non-serializable type into bean of passivating scope

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ejb, cdi

I'm learning Java EE 7.

I'm trying to store the user session in a `@SessionScoped` Backing Bean but my IDE is telling me that I have an error because "Cannot inject bean of non-serializable type into bean of passivating scope".

The `@SessionScoped` bean:

```
import negocio.Autenticacion;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserSesion implements Serializable{

    @Inject
    private Autenticacion auth; // Error by IDE


}
```

@Stateless EJB code:

```
import modelo.Usuario;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

@Stateless
public class AutenticacionBean implements Autenticacion{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Banco-PU")
    private EntityManager em;
...
```

Why can't I Inject the EJB in the backing bean?

IDE: Intellij IDEA 14.1.4

Comment: Someone has reported this issue in IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224468. If someone has experienced this issue, please vote for this issue.
Currently, you can also disable this inspection in IDEA as a workaround (may no be a good idea).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a false error. The IDE in question apparently isn't smart enough to detect that it's actually an EJB, not a "simple" CDI (or JSF) managed bean. EJBs are always implicitly serializable.

You've 4 options:

1. Ignore it. It'll run perfectly fine.
2. Bow for the false error and let EJB class implement `Serializable` anyway.
3. Use `@javax.ejb.EJB` instead of `@javax.inject.Inject` to inject it. It'll also inject the EJB, but the average IDE must be smart enough to not complain about serialization this way, because the IDE now knows for sure that it's actually an EJB, not a CDI managed bean.
4. Upgrade IDE to a newer version where this is fixed, if any. The ability to use `@Inject` instead of `@EJB` on EJBs is new since Java EE 7 (althouth the support is less complete; e.g. referencing self in `@Asynchronous` won't work when using `@Inject`). If still not fixed in latest IDE version, even though it claims to be Java EE 7 compatible, report a bug to them.

Comment: `@EJB` does not work exactly the same: you would lose the ability to use CDI interceptors/decorators (and for stateful beans, which is not the case for this question, you would lose the ability to use CDI scopes). Perhaps that doesn't matter for this case, but just mentioning for anyone that finds this answer in the future.